# How do you show public methods of a class in IntelliJ documentation?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javadoc

I'm new to IntelliJ and haven't used Java in a while so I find the Quick Documentation invaluable. However, it only shows the class definition of JavaDoc whereas I'd like this **plus** it's public methods, variables, etc. - it's interface. Is there a way to make it show all of a class' documentation and not just the header info?

Comment: Okay, that's a quick information. Intellij doesn't get this information from internet. You can't get more information from Intellij. But there is links in quick information so you can go to class' documentation.